# Complex SQL select query in messages table

Tags: sql

I have the following table in SQL called messages.
[image]

As you can see,there are 2 conversations.The first is between user 1 and 2 and the second is between user 1 and 3.I want to create an sql query that will return the last message from every conversation of user 1.In this example,it will return 2 rows.The first row,it will contains the message "I'm fine!" and the second row the message "Hello,user 3".Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a least/greatest trick to group conversations together involving the same two users, regardless of on which side each user might be.  The subquery below finds the latest message time for each pair of users.  Then, we join to your original table to bring in the actual message content.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        LEAST(sessionusrID, pickedusrID) AS user_1,
        GREATEST(sessionusrID, pickedusrID) AS user_2,
        MAX(Post_time) AS latest
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY
        LEAST(sessionusrID, pickedusrID),
        GREATEST(sessionusrID, pickedusrID)
) t2
    ON LEAST(t1.sessionusrID, t1.pickedusrID) = t2.user_1 AND
       GREATEST(t1.sessionusrID, t1.pickedusrID) = t2.user_2 AND
       t1.Post_time = t2.latest;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that in the demo I slightly altered your sample data to give the `I'm fine` message the latest date.  You had two records for the user 1/2 conversation with the same message time, and hence there was no clear latest message per your expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If two rows are acceptable, I would just do:

```
(select m.*
 from messages m
 where 1 in (sessionusrID, pickedusrID)
 order by m.post_time asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select m.*
 from messages m
 where 1 in (sessionusrID, pickedusrID)
 order by m.post_time desc
 limit 1
);
```

If you want one row with two columns, use subqueries, such as:

```
select first.*, last.*
from (select m.*
      from messages m
      where 1 in (sessionusrID, pickedusrID)
      order by m.post_time asc
      limit 1
     ) first cross join
     (select m.*
      from messages m
      where 1 in (sessionusrID, pickedusrID)
      order by m.post_time desc
      limit 1
     ) last
```